# NPM installs different version from package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, pixi.js

For our Electron app we need a specific version of pixi.js (5.0.0-rc.3). In our package.json we therefore specified `"pixi.js": "^5.0.0-rc.3",`.

When we run `npm install` now and open our app then the welcome message by pixi and the package-lock.json state version 5.0.4. We tried removing the `node_modules` folder and reinstalling all modules but it still got the wrong version.

Our import statement in the html file is `const PIXI = require('pixi.js');` and this should get the locally installed version of pixi if I am not mistaken.

Is this a bug? Or is it on purpose (if yes, which purpose)?

**Update**

As there are some answers and comments now, here's what we further tried so far:

- Delete `package-lock.json`, node_modules folder (locally and globally) and ran `npm i` again
- Reinstall NodeJS (LTS)
- Tested everything with current version of NodeJS
- Removed the '^' from the package.json as it is ok with any version in the range installing
- Tested it on another Windows 10 machine and on macOS

**Update 2**

There are three answers now and none could solve the problem so far, I'm starting to believe that this isn't my fault, but may be a bug with Pixi JS. I opened an issue [on their GitHub page](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/5851), maybe they can help.

Comment: can you try again removing`package-lock.json` and/or `npm-shrinkwrap`?

Comment: Did both of these, still installs 5.0.4. @AritraChakraborty

Comment: If you have a package-lock.json, running `npm ci` instead of `npm install` will never mutate the package.json / package-lock.json and should guarantee same versions.

Comment: You actually specified you want version `5.anything..`. If you ONLY want `5.0.0-rc.3` specify `"pixi.js": "5.0.0-rc.3"` -- remove the `^` sign

Comment: @slebetman Thank you for the tip! Sadly this didn't fix the error.

Comment: I've tested it on my machine and can 100% guarantee that installing pixi.js 5.0.0-rc.3 does not install version 5.0.4. Are you sure you've removed the old 5.0.4 version from your disk? Npm will not remove files from your disk. Running `npm install` will not downgrade pixi.js. You need to delete everything (normally the node_modules directory but I don't know your Electron build pipeline) and run `npm install` again

Comment: I reinstalled node JS 10.16. on my machine, deleted the local and the global node_modules folder, changed the entry to `"pixi.js": "5.0.0-rc.3",`, deleted the package-lock file and ran NPM install again and it still shows 5.0.4 in the console and the package-lock file. I'm using Windows 10 latest version.

Comment: I tried this with the latest version of node JS now, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** The solution is to explicitly specify the exact versions of the @pixi sub-modules in your `package.json` like this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@pixi/core": "5.0.0-rc.3",
  ... (all other pixi submodules here) ...
  "pixi.js": "5.0.0-rc.3"
}
```

**Detailed explanation:**

You *are* installing pixi.js module version 5.0.0-rc.3, but this is actually just a container for a bunch of pixi sub-modules with their own versions. The sub-module dependencies are specified like `@pixi/core": "^5.0.0-rc.3";` the `^` causes npm to grab more recent versions.

I was able to control the version of the sub-modules by adding them to the `package.json` file, next to the dependency for `pixi.js`

---

Here are the steps I used to confirm what was happening and to list the pixi sub-modules:

```sh
npm init -y                             ## Create empty npm module
npm install pixi.js@5.0.0-rc.3 --save --save-exact  ## Add pixi.js
cat package-lock.json                   ## See below
```

```
...
    "@pixi/core": {
      "version": "5.0.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@pixi/core/-/core-5.0.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-P2K2JJC+BFZrRZT9P0+Ir8jd7VrH6w7/L1Njg2+iSetW9TdjkPahR+w93VGwpEzEkrYHoNs6FbSFCY38P/6g8A==",
      "requires": {
        "@pixi/constants": "^5.0.4",
        "@pixi/display": "^5.0.4",
        "@pixi/math": "^5.0.4",
        "@pixi/runner": "^5.0.4",
        "@pixi/settings": "^5.0.4",
        "@pixi/ticker": "^5.0.4",
        "@pixi/utils": "^5.0.4"
      }
    },
...
    "pixi.js": {
      "version": "5.0.0-rc.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/pixi.js/-/pixi.js-5.0.0-rc.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-+B6ZMvJNEz/IoiC+BrwP9PsDonEAj4TOZw+yuZ/K8WQokcSm9uAp3PJ+6eFFWTjnkxsAcMP9tgldmDdTFoAF7w==",
      "requires": {
        "@pixi/accessibility": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/app": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/constants": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/core": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/display": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/extract": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/filter-alpha": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/filter-blur": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/filter-color-matrix": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/filter-displacement": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/filter-fxaa": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/filter-noise": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/graphics": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/interaction": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/loaders": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/math": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/mesh": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/mesh-extras": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/mixin-cache-as-bitmap": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/mixin-get-child-by-name": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/mixin-get-global-position": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/particles": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/polyfill": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/prepare": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/runner": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/settings": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/sprite": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/sprite-animated": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/sprite-tiling": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/spritesheet": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/text": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/text-bitmap": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/ticker": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/utils": "^5.0.0-rc.3"
      }
    },
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I specified it in package.json and removed the lock and node_modules and ran `npm i` but my package-lock doesn't look like yours and if I open the app it still shows 5.0.4. By now I'm really sorry, I hoped your solution would work :|

Comment: If I do the exact steps like you did in a new app, the package-lock looks the same tho!

Comment: @creyD I added a note to my answer because I had trouble composing a long comment from the mobile app.

Comment: Oh wait! I have to add every submodule to the package.json? I thought the overall module and core were enough. Gonna try it now!

Comment: This actually worked and solved the problem. I added all the dependencies and modules and reinstalled and the version was finally 5.0.0-rc.3

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install specific version don't use `~` or `^` in `package.json`, use the version exactly

> The tilde ~ matches the most recent patch version (the third number)
>   for the specified minor version (the second number).
>   **~1.2.3** will match all **1.2.x** versions but will hold off on 1.3.0.
>
> The caret ^ is more relaxed. It matches the most recent minor version
>   (the second number) for the specified major version (the first
>   number).
>   **^1.2.3** will match any **1.x.x** release including 1.3.0, but will
>   hold off on 2.0.0.

In your case: `"pixi.js": "5.0.0-rc.3"`

From: [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Comment: Thank you very much! Sadly I did all the steps and it still installs the 5.0.4. I'm really bummed as I thought that this was the problem... :|

Comment: I tried to install manually, it installed. So, maybe  you can install it manually.

Comment: I tried this aswell, after removing it from the `package.json` but in the app it still shows 5.0.4. What did your `package-lock.json` state after your ran this?

Comment: Removing that bit, in my package lock it is shown `5.0.4` not 5.0.0. Maybe you need to direct npm install from github. I will check and post it here. Maybe this is pixi.js's problem, not yours.

Comment: Yeah same happens on my PC. Maybe they redirected everyone from the `5.0.0-rc-3` to `5.0.4` because of a bug or something similar.

Comment: @creyD That sounds very unlikely. Are you sure you've deleted the node_modules directory and ran npm-install again?

Comment: @slebetman yeah I did. I deleted the local and global node_modules, reinstalled nodeJS (therefore npm), deleted package-lock and reran `npm install` and the console still states version 5.0.4, as does the newly created package-lock.

Comment: The console even shows during install `> pixi.js@5.0.0-rc.3 postinstall PATH\node_modules\pixi.js
> node scripts/support-pixi.js`

Answer (score 0):

**Original Answer**

If you absolutely need that version you should:

- update your `package.json` file to `"pixi.js": "5.0.0-rc.3"`.
- Delete the existing `package-lock.json` or `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file.
- Rerun `npm i`

By doing this you are pinning your dependency to that specific version.

Also check out this [semver calculator](https://semver.npmjs.com/). You can load the pixi.js package.  Then enter `5.0.0-rc.3` and `^5.0.0-rc.3`.  It will show you how the `^` changes the behavior of finding matches.

I've found that the calculator often visually helps to understand semver math better than reading the docs does for some folks.

Hope this helps!

**Updated Answer**

If you look at the package-lock.json file and look at the dependencies for `pixi.js` all of the dependencies use the `^` and are not pinning the version to `5.0.0-rc3`. Instead, they are being forced up to the latest patch version, which is `5.0.4` and a setting on NPMs/ pixis side, not yours.

```
    "pixi.js": {
      "version": "5.0.0-rc.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/pixi.js/-/pixi.js-5.0.0-rc.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-+B6ZMvJNEz/IoiC+BrwP9PsDonEAj4TOZw+yuZ/K8WQokcSm9uAp3PJ+6eFFWTjnkxsAcMP9tgldmDdTFoAF7w==",
      "requires": {
        "@pixi/accessibility": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/app": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/constants": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/core": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/display": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/extract": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/filter-alpha": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/filter-blur": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/filter-color-matrix": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/filter-displacement": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/filter-fxaa": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/filter-noise": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/graphics": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/interaction": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/loaders": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/math": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/mesh": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/mesh-extras": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/mixin-cache-as-bitmap": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/mixin-get-child-by-name": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/mixin-get-global-position": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/particles": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/polyfill": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/prepare": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/runner": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/settings": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/sprite": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/sprite-animated": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/sprite-tiling": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/spritesheet": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/text": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/text-bitmap": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/ticker": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
        "@pixi/utils": "^5.0.0-rc.3"
      }
    },
```

It looks like if you want this to work, and I would really just advise you to update your app to work with the updated package instead of doing this, you'll need to

- fork pixi.js at the `5.0.0-rc3` tag, https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/tree/v5.0.0-rc.3
- Update the `package.json` file to make all of it's dependencies `5.0.0-rc.3` instead of `^5.0.0-rc.3`
- Create a dependency on your forked repository instead of the published npm module.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sadly I did all the steps and it still installs the 5.0.4.

Comment: BTW: the semver calculator only showed the 5.0.0-rc.3 and nothing else.

Comment: I think I see what the issue is.  I updated my answer to reflect what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue where instead of required tildify 2.0.0 it was always installing 3.0.0 version.
**Note** -
I have been trying updating package.json file manually to change the version but that did *not* help.
Here are the commands I used that finally saved my day -

Step 1 - Remove node_modules folder manually

Step 2 - from your package.json directory, run this command to uninstall the package

```
npm uninstall <package_name>
```

example -

```
npm uninstall tildify
```

Step 3 - from your package.json directory, run this command to install the package with exact version

```
npm install <package_name>@<package_version> --save-dev --save-exact
```

example -

```
npm install tildify@2.0.0 --save-dev --save-exact
```